# How to validate request body in Node.js, Express - is it possible without using a library?

Tags: node.js, express, validation, request, express-validator

I have the code (below) and one developer said to me that I had to validate my request:

```
router.post('/dashboard', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
(req, res) => {

    try {
        let newPost = new Post({
            category: req.body.category,
            title: req.body.title,
            photo: req.body.photo,
            text: req.body.text,
            author: req.body.author,
            date: req.body.date
        });

        Post.addPost(newPost, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                res.json({success: false, msg: `Post has not been added. ${err}`})
            } else {
                res.json({success: true, msg: 'Post was added.'})
            }
        })
    } catch (err) {
       const error = (res, error) => {
            res.status(500).json({
                success: false,
                message: error.message ? error.message : error
            })
       }

       console.log('error routes/auth POST', res, error)
    }
})
```

I googled and found the solutions i.e. using libraries for request validation like `express-validator` - is it ok?

Are there any native, built-in express, *node.js* methods to validate a request?

Or it's better to use a library like `express-validator`?

Comment: Can recommend [Joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi), but [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-validator) is also ok. It's much better than write your own validators.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Express.js doesn't have a built-in validator.
But you can use [express-validator](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/)  or [joi](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.5.0). Both of these libraries are good.

if you are using typescript in your project [class-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator) is a better option, it will let you use types.

And this is a great talk on why you need to validate the data. [Take Data Validation Seriously by Paul Milham](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bfqCQFD9L6k)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late!
Unfortunately, **ExpressJs** does not have build-in validation. You can use [Zod](https://zod.dev/) to validate your request's (params, query or body) payloads by creating a custom middleware or use a package like [zod-express-middleware](https://github.com/Aquila169/zod-express-middleware)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above Express.js does not have its own built-in validator. You can also check this library [simple-body-validator](https://www.simple-body-validator.com), it offers an experience similar to the Laravel validation

Answer (score 0):

We can use Yup for Express Validation: https://github.com/jquense/yup

Example:

```
import * as yup from 'yup'

const userCreateSchema = yup.object({
  email: yup.string().email().required(),
  password: yup.string().required(),
})
const result = await userCreateSchema.validate(req.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide an openapi/swagger file to publish how to use your api, and have your service validate against the models in the spec then I recommend using [openapi-backend](https://www.npmjs.com/package/openapi-backend)