# Typescript Type Check

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I am receiving an express request, is there a way/package that can make sure the body is conformed to a certain type, something like this

```
type SampleRequestBody = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: {
      city: string;
      street_num: number;
      street_name: string;
  };
  balance?: number;
}

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const isCorrectType: boolean = someMethod(req.body, SampleRequestBody);
  if (isCorrectType) {
      res.status(200).send("Correct Type!");
    } else {
      res.status(400).send("Incorrect Type!");
}
```

So basically just make sure all mandatory tags are correctly typed!

**Note:** I know types can't be passed to a function, I am just trying to explain what I am trying to do!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate request body in Node.js, Express - is it possible without using a library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70256124/how-to-validate-request-body-in-node-js-express-is-it-possible-without-using)

Comment: TypeScript metadata **does not exist** at runtime, it's removed in transpilation to JavaScript.

Comment: You can use https://express-validator.github.io/docs/

Answer (score 0):

Passing types to functions is not possible because types are not functional in compiled JavaScript from TypeScript.

So most closer approach to your problem is using `classes`.

I highly recommend to use [class-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator) for validating request body with classes. Also you can use OOP methods to implement your type to validator classes.