Is there a way to reduce if else conditions while validating all the keys of a request payload?
I have a request payload with multiple keys (about 20 to 30) like name, email, phone number, address etc and some of these are optional.
To validate those I use multiple if/else conditions and in some cases I need to include validation based on a dependent key too.
For example: If I have a value in the address key, then values for the city, state and zip keys are mandatory. In this scenario I have a bunch of if/else conditions in my code. Is there a way to minimize the if conditions and improve my code?
I'm expecting to reduce the number of if/else conditions
Edit: It's a working code and the it's is in server side with Javascript, Nodejs.
For eg the code is like as below:
if(!request.name || !(regex test for request.name) {
  error += Invalid/ missing name
}
if(!request.email || !(regex test for request.email) {
  error += Invalid/ missing email
}
if(!request.username || !(regex test for request.username) {
  error += Invalid/ missing username
}
if(request.address && !request.city && !request.state) {
  error += Missing address info
}

It follows the same format for other fields too

If you have working code that you think could be improved, see [codereview.se]. If not, please [edit] to clarify the issue with it. Either way, people will need to see the actual code. Take the [tour] and read [ask].

Where is this validation taking place? If server-side, what language are you using? If client-side, how are you going to prevent users turning off javascript and bypassing the validation?

probably practice data driven methods

it depends on where do you need to do the validations, but I usually using data validation libs when I need proper validations, one of the good ones out there is Yup.

Since JavaScript, NodeJS and TS are tagged in the post, maybe some of the answers to this question would help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70256124/4018331

Given the example you show, this is a form validation issue. In HTML5, form validation can be handled automatically, without having to code a single line of javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

It might be easier to handle the logic differently in order to avoid the if/else soup. You can create an object that defines the validation rules for each parameter, which you can then iterate over to perform the validation. Below is an example of how you can structure this object and use it for validation. Add a rule for every param you wish to validate.


const validationRules = [
  {
    param: "name",
    validation: function(request) {
      // optional, only validate if non-empty
      return request[this.param] ? /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/.test(request[this.param]) : true;
    },
    errorMessage: "Invalid name",
  },
  {
    param: "email",
    validation: function(request) {
      // required
      return /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/.test(request[this.param]);
    },
    errorMessage: "Invalid/missing email",
  },
  {
    param: "username",
    validation: function(request) {
      // required
      return /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/.test(request[this.param]);
    },
    errorMessage: "Invalid/missing username",
  },
  {
    param: "address",
    validation: function(request) {
      // optional but requires city and state if filled
      return request.address ? request.city && request.state : true;
    },
    errorMessage: "Missing address info",
  },
];

// Function to perform validation
function validateRequest(request) {
  let errorMessages = [];

  validationRules.forEach((rule) => {
    if (!rule.validation(request)) {
      errorMessages.push(rule.errorMessage);
    }
  });

  return errorMessages;
}

// Example usage:
const request = {
  name: "John 66 Doe", 
  email: "johndoe@example.com", 
  username: "john_doe123", 
  address: "123 Main St", 
  city: "",
  state: "",
};

const errors = validateRequest(request);

if (errors.length > 0) {
  console.log("Validation Errors:", errors);
} else {
  console.log("Validation Passed!");
}



